# Identify the space of spherical harmonics and the space of homogenous polynomials

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spherical-harmonics

Is there an explicit way to identify the space of spherical harmonics and the space of homogeneous polynomials over $\mathbb{C}^2$?

I know that the space of spherical harmonics can be seen the irreducible representation of $SO(3)$. Is there a way to identify the space geometrically?

I was taking of using the map $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. But I'm not super familiar with geometry.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There's no such thing as the space of homogeneous polynomials over $\mathbb C^2$. If you add two homogeneous polynomials of different degrees, you don't get a homogeneous polynomial. I suspect what you may be trying to do is to identify the space of spherical harmonics for a certain value of $l$ with the space of homogoneous polynomials of degree $l$?

Comment: What do you mean by "geometrically"? Certainly it is a basic fact of representations of Lie groups that the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ (which we note has the same Lie algebra as $SU(2)$) are simply symmetric powers of $\mathbb{C}^2$ i.e. they are the spaces of symmetric polynomials of a fixed degree. Is it this identification you wish to understand or why they are the irreducible representations in the first place?

Comment: Note: it is a bit inaccurate to say they are representations of $SO(3)$ in fact, as in this case some of the $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ representations do not actually give rise to $SO(3)$ representations (the spin representation for example) but they are all representations of $SU(2) = \mathrm{Spin}(3)$, the double cover.

Comment: @Callum: In https://desvl.xyz/2022/06/16/so3-laplacian/, it says the space of spherical harmonics is isomorphism to $W_l$. Isn't $W_l$ the irreducible representation of $SO(3)$? Thanks!